# Одна маска для нескольких картинок

Tags: html, css, mask

В header была повторяющаяся фоновая картинка в виде волны (1):

```
div {
  height: 389px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/JzBYfAN.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Понадобилось добавить еще две фоновых картинки (2) и (3). (2) прилипает к левому краю окна, (3) к правому.

При этом их нижний край должен был повторять форму волны. Непонятно было как применить одну маску к нескольким картинкам.

[image: header]

При изменении ширины окна волна плывет, а картинки (2) и (3) остаются по краям.

Comment: Сделайте код воспроизводимым  с вашей ошибкой, сложно понять только по описанию что именно у вас не получается

Answer (score 0):

Сначала пробовал добавлять новые картинки в отдельный div и к ним применять маску, но из этого ничего не вышло. Из-за плывущей волны правая картинка никак не поддавалась.

Методом проб и ошибок воспользовался multiple backgrounds и применил маску к нему.

```css
header {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

div {
  height: 389px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/I9zuTj4.png), url(https://i.imgur.com/EhlutXw.png), url(https://i.imgur.com/JzBYfAN.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom left -110px, bottom right, bottom left;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/JzBYfAN.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: bottom left;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div></div>
</header>
```